# how to increase the size of scroll track in jquery jscrollpane

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-jscrollpane

I changed the size of the scroll bar in jScrollpane

```
$(function()
            {
                $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
                    verticalDragMinHeight: 30,
                    verticalDragMaxHeight: 32,
                    horizontalDragMinWidth: 40,
                    horizontalDragMaxWidth: 40
                });
            });
```

But i am not able to change the size of the track it has.

PFB the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use below updated css..

```
.jspVerticalBar
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 27px;
height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.You need to set the preferred size of the JScrollBar components. Using your initial approach you can do:

```
     scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(
new Dimension(width, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
scrollpane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(
new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, width));
```

Credit goes to this post [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474706/change-side-of-a-jscrollpane-change-size)

Also you can use CSS to do that like so:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Here is another resource on how to use [jScrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/drag_size.html)

Comment: this is jquery jscrollpane, not the java one